# uninitialized constant Devise (NameError) unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capistrano, unicorn, devise-token-auth

I deployed my rails app with capistrano to digitalocean and after adding new gem `gem 'devise_token_auth', '1.0.0'` after deploying I faced strange issue in unicorn log. It is bellow

```js
E, [2019-05-09T17:49:37.285001 #19550] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
/home/deploy/www/smole-app-back/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/home/deploy/www/smole-app-back/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
/home/deploy/www/smole-app-back/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
/home/deploy/www/smole-app-back/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/deploy/www/smole-app-back/releases/20190509174241/config/initializers/devise.rb:1:in `<main>'
/home/deploy/www/smole-app-back/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/home/deploy/www/smole-app-back/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/home/deploy/www/smole-app-back/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-
```

I found the same issue from 2013 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719676/uninitialized-constant-devise-nameerror), but answer is not clear, can somebody help me?

unicorn - 5.5.0
bundler 1.16.0
ruby 2.5.3